# Shell script to rename multiple files from their parent folders name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, rename

I have a file structure like  this:

- 00000010

  - 000000001.file1
  - 000000001.file2
- 00000020

  - 00000003.file1
  - 00000003.file2
  - 00000003.file3
- ...

So there are folders with 8-digit names containing one ore more files with name starting with 8-digit numbers. But theses filenames are – let's say – out of sync. So Now I try to rename them recursively in bash to archive:

- 00000010

  - 000000010.file1
  - 000000010.file2
- 00000020

  - 00000020.file1
  - 00000020.file2
  - 00000020.file3
- ...

My script does look like:

```
#! /bin/bash

find * -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -type d | while read -r dir
do
        rename 's/$dir\/[0-9]{8}/$dir/' *
done
```

But this is not working and gives errors like

> Global symbol "$dir" requires explicit
>   package name at (eval 1) line 1.

How could I write it to rename the files according to their folder names?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/240307/shell-script-to-rename-multiple-files-from-their-parent-folders-name).

Comment: Ok, already thought that this might not be the best idea. Will not happen again! Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"` in place of `'` in `rename`

You should run `rename` on the files inside `$dir`, so the argument to `rename` must be `$dir/*` and not just `*`

Since you want to replace `dir/8digits` with `dir/dir` the replacement part of the regex should be `$dir\/$dir`

With the above changes the command looks like:

```
rename "s/$dir\/[0-9]{8}/$dir\/$dir/" $dir/*
```

Answer (score 4):

`rename` is actually a Perl script.

Here's how you could do it using only `bash` and `mv`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in *; do
    if test -d "$dir"; then
        (
            cd $dir
            for file in *; do
                newfile=$dir.${file#*.}
                mv "$file" "$newfile"
            done
        )
    fi
done
```

First a script to reproduce your directory tree:

```
$ i=1
$ for dir in 000000{1..2}0; do
mkdir $dir
touch $dir/0000000$i.file{1..3}
i=$((i+1))
done
$ find .
.
./00000010
./00000010/00000001.file1
./00000010/00000001.file2
./00000010/00000001.file3
./00000020
./00000020/00000002.file3
./00000020/00000002.file2
./00000020/00000002.file1
```

And now showing the script working:

```
$ ../ren.sh
$ find .
.
./00000010
./00000010/00000010.file1
./00000010/00000010.file2
./00000010/00000010.file3
./00000020
./00000020/00000020.file1
./00000020/00000020.file2
./00000020/00000020.file3
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `*` in your find command is misplaced -- you need to give a directory to start searching. `.` is usual.

Second, `$dir` in your perl rename command won't be expanded by the shell because the whole string is quoted.

Third, the `*` you are handing to your perl rename command will expand to all the directories *and files* in your current working directory, which is probably not what you intended.

@Mikel's answer is much nicer than what I was working on, but I thought this might still be useful. :)